# cypher how to create unique nodes from substring of other nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, unique, relationship

I am new to Cypher and Neo4j.  I have a set of nodes labeled "Line" each line is a long string such as:
`0067011990999991950051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+00001+99999999999`

There are two substrings that I care about: `year` and `temp`

```
match(l:Line)
return toInteger(substring(l.line,15,4)) as year, toInteger(substring(l.line,87,5)) as temp
limit (5)
```

In order to give:

```
year    temp

1941    44

1942    90

1942    12

1948    100

1948    -21
```

I need to create a set of nodes labeled "Year" for each unique value of year, a set of noes labeled "Temp" for each unique temp reading. I also needs to relate each year to its temp readings using the relationship has_temp.  (and then print the year, the temp reading and relationship type in desc sorted order of the year.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
match(l:Line) 
with toInteger(substring(l.line,15,4)) as year, 
toInteger(substring(l.line,87,5)) as temp
MERGE (y:Year{value:year})
MERGE (t:Temp{value:temp})
MERGE (y)-[s:has_temp]->(t)
RETURN year,temp,type(s) as rel_type order by year desc
```

If you want to check how it imported nodes later you can do:

```
MATCH (y:Year)-[r]->(t:Temp)
RETURN y.value as year,t.value as temp,type(r) as re_tzpe order by year desc
```

Comment: How do I get the year(s) with the highest number of readings?     I know I can do something like MATCH (y:Year)-[r]->(t:Temp)
RETURN y.value as year, count(t.value) as temp_readings
order by temp_readings desc limit 2 ;

-- resutlts
year temp_readings
1950 106
1951 75         I may have many years with same highest number of readings, so limit is not a good way.  any other ideas?   thanks.